# html opacity does not show on link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a link opacity by `0.5` when I hover the element.

However, the text shows `opacity:0.5` without needing to hover.

this is my code:

```
#a1
{
 position:absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 top: 503px;
 color:#085da2;
 opacity:1.0;
 }

#a1 a
{
color:#085da2;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

what I want is #a1 to show as 1.0, but however when the page loads it shows 0.5 instead:/

Comment: opacity is already working there. I think, you want to do something on `:hover`

Comment: You might want to read the W3 CSS specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text shows `opacity:0.5` without hover to it because you have directly apply opacity. Instead try this..

```
#a1 a
{
position:absolute;font-weight: bold;top: 503px;color:blue;
opacity:1.0;
}
```

To giving hover effect use `:hover` attribute to anchor link, like

```
#a1 a:hovor
{
color:#085da2;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have, now my #a is showing green, when i have called it blue!

Comment: set or replace color you want, in `#a1 a`. see my updated answer. let me know if you have still issue with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:hover`

```
#a1 a:hover {
   color:#085da2;
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

- a:link - a normal, unvisited link
- a:visited - a link the user has visited
- a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
- a:active - a    link the moment it is clicked

Update after comment:

```
a:link {
    color: #009900;   /* This is your green color*/
}
```

Change it to `color:#085da2;`

With `#a1 {color:#085da2; }` You dont change the `<a>` (link) color.. You should specify it as `#a1 a {color:#085da2; }`.

Comment: i have, now my #a is showing green, when i have called it blue!

Comment: thats strange because you hex color is blue..., there should be something more in your code..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a style to be applyed on hover, you have to define a :hover rule. You want this:

```
#a1 a:Hover,
#a1 a:Focus
{
    color:#085da2;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the hover pseudo class. So you code will be as follows:

```
#a1
{
   position:absolute;font-weight: bold;top: 503px;color:#085da2;
   opacity:1.0;
}

#a1 a:hover
{
   color:#085da2;
   opacity:0.5;
}
```